# Are 'type' and 'method' equivalent in jQuery ajax calls?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am reading the jquery docs and it suggested to use the keyword `method` to use an http verb in a given path. Like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "path",
            method: "POST",
```

However, i found out code that uses the keyword `type` instead of method followed by the http verb.

Is `type` and `method` the same thing? Or does the code i read do something different?

I opened the docs but there is no specification of keyword `type`.

Comment: What docs were you looking at?

Comment: @isherwood http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Ctrl-f, `type (default: 'GET')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0. use `type`

`method` was added in version `1.9.0`

> **method** (default: 'GET')
>   Type: String
>   The HTTP method to use for the request (e.g. "POST", "GET", "PUT"). (version added: 1.9.0)

[$.ajax() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)